# Excel Form pops automatically when sheet opens

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I have a specific worksheet with 2 sheets(Sheet1 & Sheet2). For Sheet2 I have implemented a form for the table (Using the basic Excel Form from the top bar).

My problem is that I have to make the form appear automatically every time I open Sheet1 (even if the data from the form will be completed in Sheet2).

Is this possible? Or how can I do it? (I can also use VBA)

Comment: You need to provide more details if you want to get help. What kind of form did you implement? I do not know what you mean with "Excel Form from the top bar". It seems you are not talking about a [userform.](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/)

Comment: @Storax it s not a VBA form, this is the form that I'm talking about: https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/create-data-entry-form-excel/

Comment: Are you using Excel 2016 btw?

Comment: @QHarr Excel 2007

Answer (score 3):

To show the DataForm associated with a Worksheet, you use the command `Worksheet.ShowDataForm` ([MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.showdataform))

To show the DataForm for `Sheet1` whenever you go to `Sheet2`, you can use the `Worksheet_Activate` event in `Sheet2`, like so:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Sheet1.ShowDataForm
End Sub
```

A quick way to figure things like this out is use the "Record Macro" button, carry out the action you want, and then hit "Stop Recording" and look at the macro

Comment: There is also a keyboard shortcut to start this form. If the cursor is located in the table I can start the form with Alt-N-M (german version!)

Comment: It may be worth being a a bit more explicit that this code needs to go in the sheet's code, and not in a regular module.